# Checking value of property of type UnauthorizedAccessException

Tags: .net, windows, vb.net, security, exception

I'm trying to figure out if a user has admin rights on a particular server by calling the following code:

```vb
Dim serverContext As New PrincipalContext(ContextType.Machine, myServerName)
```

If they don't, the `ConnectedServer` property on the `PrincipleContext` object turns into type `System.UnathorizedAccessException` and the value is `{"Access is denied."}`

But I can't seem to run any check in code to see if this is the case or not or wether the connected server property set normally as a string.

These won't work, and I can't figure out why

```vb
Dim bln1 = serverContext.ConnectedServer = "Access is denied."
Dim bln2 = TypeOf serverContext.ConnectedServer Is System.UnauthorizedAccessException
```

[image]

Comment: What that's telling you is that attempting to access the `serverContext.ConnectedServer` property threw `UnauthorizedAccessException`. That is *not* the value (or type) of the property. In code, you surround code that accesses that property with a Try/Catch block to catch those exceptions if they occur when running your program. Look into exception handling for more info.